# Getting rid of extra lines in Python shapefile plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, gis, shapefile

I am trying to do a basic plot of the world map using Python and the Matplotlib library. However, when I plot the polygons the plot shows many straight lines that do not seem to be part of the polygon. I am relatively new at working with shapefiles but the code I'm using has worked for a previous shapefile I used, so I'm confused and wondering what might be missing in the code.

The code I'm using is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import shapefile as shp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import os

sns.set(style='whitegrid', palette='ocean', color_codes=True)
sns.mpl.rc('figure', figsize=(10,6))

sf = shp.Reader(shp_path)

def plot_map(sf, x_lim = None, y_lim = None, figsize = (11,9)):
    '''
    Plot map with lim coordinates
    '''
    plt.figure(figsize = figsize)
    id=0
    for shape in sf.shapeRecords():
        x = [i[0] for i in shape.shape.points[:]]
        y = [i[1] for i in shape.shape.points[:]]
        plt.plot(x, y, 'k')

        if (x_lim == None) & (y_lim == None):
            x0 = np.mean(x)
            y0 = np.mean(y)
            plt.text(x0, y0, id, fontsize=10)
        id = id+1

    if (x_lim != None) & (y_lim != None):
        plt.xlim(x_lim)
        plt.ylim(y_lim)

plot_map(sf)
plt.show()
```

The following link shows resulting graph (I'm not allowed to post pictures yet?):

[image: Resulting Graph]

Any help is appreciated, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

pls use 'k.', or use `scatter` instead of `plot`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import shapefile as shp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import os

sns.set(style='whitegrid', palette='ocean', color_codes=True)
sns.mpl.rc('figure', figsize=(10,6))

sf = shp.Reader(shp_path)

def plot_map(sf, x_lim = None, y_lim = None, figsize = (11,9)):
    '''
    Plot map with lim coordinates
    '''
    plt.figure(figsize = figsize)
    id=0
    for shape in sf.shapeRecords():
        x = [i[0] for i in shape.shape.points[:]]
        y = [i[1] for i in shape.shape.points[:]]
        ## change here
        plt.plot(x, y, 'k.')

        if (x_lim == None) & (y_lim == None):
            x0 = np.mean(x)
            y0 = np.mean(y)
            plt.text(x0, y0, id, fontsize=10)
        id = id+1

    if (x_lim != None) & (y_lim != None):
        plt.xlim(x_lim)
        plt.ylim(y_lim)

plot_map(sf)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! With the change you suggest the map indeed looks tidier. However, the countries borders are not "closed" by straight line which is what I'm looking for, but remain open. Is there a way to join each data point of the scatter with a line without getting my previous error?